# PHP - MySQL - Sign Up Trouble [blank data]

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, registration

I've a website since 2013. I've signed up quite 12k users. From 5 months I have noticed some blank users. They receive a user-code but "name" "surname" and "email" fields are blanks.
This event happen every 50/100 users registrations. Why? I have tried everything, but in all test I can't sign up without data. Also other people that have made tests can't sign up without insert data.
This is the form:

```
<form action="script/****.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" <?php if($_REQUEST['name'] != "") echo "value='".$_REQUEST['name']."'"; ?> />

<label for="surname">Surname</label>
<input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" <?php if($_REQUEST['surname'] != "") echo "value='".$_REQUEST['surname']."'"; ?> />

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" <?php if($_REQUEST['email'] != "") echo "value='".$_REQUEST['email']."'"; ?> />

<label for="c_email">Retype Email</label>
<input type="email" id="c_email" name="c_email" />

<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" />

<label for="c_password">Retype Password</label>
<input type="password" id="c_password" name="c_password" />

<input type="submit" value="registrati" />
</form>
```

This is the code that stores data on db:

```
<?php
    function mt_rand_str ($length, $available = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789') {
        for ($string = '', $i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
            $string .= $available[mt_rand(0, strlen($available)-1)];
        }
        return $string;
    }

    include('connection.php');
    $con = connection();
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $bonus = 10;
    $today = new DateTime();
    $signUpDate = $today->format('Y-m-d');

    if(strpos($name,'  ') !== false) {
        echo "
        <script>
        alert('Nome non valido!');
        window.location.href = '../signup.php';
        </script>";
        exit;
    }
    if(strpos($surname,'  ') !== false) {
        echo "
        <script>
        alert('Cognome non valido!');
        window.location.href = '../signup.php';
        </script>";
        exit;
    }
    if(strpos($email,' ') !== false) {
        echo "
        <script>
        alert('Email non valida!');
        window.location.href = '../signup.php';
        </script>";
        exit;
    }
    if(strpos($password,' ') !== false) {
        echo "
        <script>
        alert('Password non valida!');
        window.location.href = '../signup.php';
        </script>";
        exit;
    }

    connectionCheck($con);
    userDbCheck($con);

    $checkEmail = mysqli_query($con,"Select * from Users_DB where email = '$email'");
    if(!mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkEmail)) {
        do {
            $userCode = mt_rand_str(8);
        }
        while(mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"select * from Users_DB where binary UserCode = '$userCode'")));

        $value = 20;

        mysqli_query($con,"Insert into User_DB (UserCode,Name,Surname,Phone,Email,Password,SignUpDate,bonus)
                                values ('$userCode','$name','$surname','','$email','$password','$signUpDate','$bonus')");
    }
    else {
        echo "
        <script>
            alert('Email exists already!');
            window.location.href = '../signup.php';
        </script>";
    }
?>
```

I hope you can find what I have not. As you can see, I've put in php code some data check too.
So I have
1) HTML5 check: type="email". I'm thinking to put also "pattern match" in all fields
2) JavaScript check
3) PHP check
I'm so desperate...
Thank you before.

Comment: do you know if it happens at registration? could they remove their name shortly after registering?

Comment: `strpos(var,' ')` checks for a space not an empty string am I wrong? So a blank string would return false since it's not a space.

Comment: It's also terrifying you are not using prepared statements and just allowing them to shove whatever the hell input the user puts in into the DB.

Comment: @Leeish They can't shove what they want in db, there is jscript. However i prefer build my script instead external script for basic operation. However php check only if there are two spaces, not if it is an empty string. For that there is always jscript.

Comment: @RightClick No, they can't edit their data since I don't solve this.

Comment: Bots often don't use javascript and I can turn it off in my browser and then use sql injection techniques to f your db up. NEVER EVER rely only on javascript to protect your database. javascript is client side and can be turned off. I'm willing to bet bots are submitting your form with blanks and you are just shoving it in there. Turn off javascript and try to submit your form. I can submit your form from my own site if I want, hell from my desktop and try to break your stuff and tear your db apart. Hope you aren't working for a business. ALWAYS sanitize and validate data server side.

Comment: @Leeish Okay, so I can solve it using PHP checking? I'm quite noob on security 'till now.

Comment: You should use prepared SQL statements (to protect from SQL injection) and validate the data in PHP. Check for characters you don't want, empty strings, valid emails, etc. If you don't you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: http://cdn.meme.am/instances2/500x/355570.jpg   @Leeish I'm laughing at that.

Comment: @Leeish Thank you so much! I'm been lucky if till now noone has injected data! I'll use this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php